# How to replace images in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a quick question. In a pdf file (with 21 pages) in top of each of them is the same image. I want to replace it with another image (just like you do with text 'find and replace') Is there any option?

Comment: What have you tried? more like a question for Adobe https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2202320

Comment: Until now I've replaced them manually, going at each of them, deleting it and replace with the other one. But it's waste of time since I have to do the same thing at each of them. I have to replace the same picture couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's not a find and replace per se, the Links palette makes this task easy and quick.

[image]

Comment: Really helpful, thank you :) I haven't thought about that before.